# is it possible to power esp8266 with button cell

Tags: esp8266

is it possible to power esp8266 wifi module with button cell for long period(1 year ) real time applications??
 Needs only wifi features (no need of gpio)

what will be voltage and current of the cell??

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYuYTfO6iOs) is worth a watch.

Answer (score 3):

No. It has to wake up to do something and turn on the wifi. At that moment it requires too much power for a button cell. It needs about 150mA, mostly for wifi.

The BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) is specifically designed for low power usage. Also some RF modules (433MHz, 868MHz, 915MHz) can be used with a small battery.

Comment: can you suggest an alternative for this problem

Comment: I agree it won't have the best lifespan, certainly not a year, but  the math shown is likely pessimistic. 150ma is on the high-end of estimations, especially for modules with the newer antenna and not far from the router. Also, those hi-energy pulses only last a ms or two; the avg draw on a short run is closer to 50ma. OP: 2 parallel coin cells can provide twice as much current, which solves potential early-shut-down issues, but not the short-lifespan ones...